# Import data into python from localhost each time it gets updated

Tags: python

I gater data constantly (interger and character) in lines and output it in localhost:30003. I would like a python script to gather the data every time it gets outputed in the localhost:30003 and save it into a file in my case log.txt.
I made a code:

```
import threading
import urllib

def printit():
  threading.Timer(1, printit).start() #I set one second but in fact it doesn't get outputed at regular intervals
  feed = URLopener.retrieve('http://localhost:30003')
  f = open("log.txt", 'a')
  f.write(str(feed))
  f.close()

printit()
```

But it doesn't do what I want it to do..., keeps printing every second:

```
<addinfourl at 1988080744 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x76b329b0>>
```

(Or similar)

Thanks,

Willfrd

Answer (score 1):

You're not reading the data from the URL.  Instead of `f.write(str(feed))`, you should use `f.write(feed.read())`

Comment: Tried to use this way but it doesn't work, it doesn't save anything :(

Comment: That suggests that the source isn't providing any data - are you sure the server is working correctly?

Comment: It is working because in the RaspberryPi where I execute the script if I run the command in the console `wget localhost:30003`I get data outputed into a index.html file, data such as `MSG,4,1,1,34520F,1,2017/04/09,01:03:18.929,2017/04/09,01:03:18.948,,,427,207,,,-64,,,,,0`, but what I want is python do save it so later on I can filter the data.

Answer (score 0):

This works,

```
import threading
import urllib

def printit():
  threading.Timer(1, printit).start() #I set one second but in fact it doesn't get outputed at regular intervals
  feed = urllib.urlopen('http://localhost:30003')
  f = open("log.txt", 'a')
  f.write(str(feed.read()))
  f.close()

printit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still not working, now it does't write anything :(

Comment: does it throw any error ? can u print `feed.read()` and check the output

Comment: No, it doesn't output anything... the localhost hosted in a RaspberryPi conected to the local network so what I do is do the changes to the script in my computer, pass the script to the RPi and run it from the SSH with `python <scriptname>.py`, I know there is data been outputed in the localhost:30003 because if I type in the console `wget localhost:30003` which saves the content of the localhost in a index.html file, an example of a line outputed `MSG,4,1,1,34520F,1,2017/04/09,01:03:18.929,2017/04/09,01:03:18.948,,,427,207,,,-64,,,,,0`

Comment: But I want python to save it to later on filter the data gathered.

Comment: if `urllib.urlopen('http://localhost:30003').read()` doesnt return output, there must be wrong with the server. Can you check if accessing `http://localhost:30003` in your web browser is returning any data /

Comment: Writing in the browser `http://localhost:30003` prints messages such as `MSG,5,1,1,405F11,1,2017/04/09,22:47:01.941,2017/04/09,22:47:01.958,,32075,,,,,,,0,,0,`, tried with `feed = urllib.urlopen('http://localhost:30003').read()` and `f.write(str(feed))` further down, but it still doesn't save anything :( Can you think of any alternatives?, thanks